# I can't find my bitcoin address and my bitcoin core is out of sync by 3 years

Tags: wallet, address, synchronization

Hey guys I am a newbie at Bitcoin just recently found out about it.

I downloaded Bitcoin core; I encrypted the wallet; I created a backup folder, but it is out of sync by 3 years 4 weeks and i can't seem to find my Bitcoin address due to it. How do I find my Bitcoin address if it is out sync?

Comment: When you say `it is out of sync`, what are you referring to?

Comment: well when i open the program it say my wallet is out of sync and on the bottom left corner it states that it is trying to synchronize with network and the last block generated was 2 years and 21 weeks ago... i don't quite understand it that well to be honest lol.

Answer (score 7):

Go to the top left, click File then receiving or sending addresses. There, you can create new adresses and look at your current addresses.

Answer (score 4):

What it means by "out of sync" is that when you download the Satoshi (original) wallet, you download the entire "Blockchain," or every transaction in Bitcoin history. This is the reason why Bitcoin is decentralized - everyone has a copy of every transaction ever. By it saying "2 years" it means it has 2 years left of transactions to download (all the transactions that happened in the past two years). Even though I'm not sure why your Bitcoin address isn't showing (might be intended?), it's not really a good idea to use Bitcoin until the 25GB blockchain is downloaded, but you can get a wallet that doesn't download it called [Multibit](https://multibit.org/).

Comment: oh I see... is there anyway to speed up the process or should i just use multibit until the 25gb blockchain is fully downloaded? oh and i managed to find the bitcoin address but i am still unsure on how to create a new address...

Comment: @D3on3 Only faster internet can speed up a Blockchain download.

Comment: @D3on3 Nevermind, see http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4474/21114 for help with speeding it up.

Comment: ahh man that's a drag. i know I have asked many questions but how exactly do you create new bitcoin addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Go to file then go to receiving addresses your receiving address is generate there if you click new you will have a new receiving address don't use the same receiving address for every receiving transaction use a different one per receiving transaction people will hack your wallet.