# Load balancing for using more than 1 Internet connection to speed up Initial Block Download (IBD)

Tags: network, synchronization, bitcoin.conf

Have invested in good networking hardware and researching on failover scenarios using 2 connections - the home broadband and mobile LTE one - as well as load balancing to increase download/upload speeds utilising both connections.

There is a document from a load balancing workshop organised by networking gear manufacturer available online, which reads:

https://mum.mikrotik.com/presentations/PL12/Load_Balancing_workshop.pdf

"Load Balancing is a technique to distribute the
workload across two or more network links in
order to maximize throughput, minimise
response time, and avoid overload"

Initial block download is notoriously painful procedure for everybody. Guess many of us have unlimited Internet connections at home as well as same mobile data plans. Network gear that does load balancing is affordable.

Has anybody tried it and if it helps - which approach/algorithm is the best?

Many thanks,
Yuri

Comment: My experience is that IBD is limited by disk IO performance not by network bandwidth.

If that also applies to your system, it should be addressed first.

Comment: Indeed. I tried IBD to USB-C adapter with NVMe drive in it and was wondering why network download was extremely slow. Then, after some research including here, found out that  should be using internal drive rather than external. Would never thought otherwise that drive performance affects network download so directly

Comment: Does https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4461/5406 or https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/69862/5406 answer your question?