# Why does it take so long to initially sync with my bitcoin wallet?

Tags: synchronization

I have downloaded the bitcoin software and I am starting it up for the first time.

However, it begins to download the entire transaction history, which takes a huge amount of time (for some reason). I thought it was my connection in the beginning, but even when I arrived home with a relatively good connection (I can download 1.5MBps without disconnections, and a good latency), it still takes very very long (It's been up for 2 whole nights, and it's not even past 50%. Either the size of it is over 500 GB (which isn't likely), or something is wrong.

Did anyone else experience the problem? Is it even a problem? (or is their server not that good?).

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/how-can-one-download-the-initial-blockchain-data-files-securely

Comment: Also: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4461/why-is-downloading-blocks-taking-longer-and-longer

Comment: What version?  Bitcoin.org client v0.8 is dramatically better for initial sync.  And you can get the blockchain data from a torrent if your download speed isn't that great.