# How should I get all transaction history in a format that I can analyze?

Tags: transactions

I want to download the entire bitcoin transaction history and store it in a database at my end to perform certain analysis. How do I get from the blk*.dat files to a useful format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one download the initial Blockchain data files securely?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/how-can-one-download-the-initial-blockchain-data-files-securely)

Comment: @HighlyIrregular Edited to not be a straight duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read information from the blockchain?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/how-can-i-read-information-from-the-blockchain)

Comment: I want the transaction information is some kind of usable format. How do I make sense of this ??

Comment: I want which public key(s) sent how much bitcion to which keys at what time for all transactions starting from the inception till now..

Comment: @user1754257 Then clarify your question. You've got an edit button for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do a similar thing to put all the transactions in the database (it was PostgreSQL for me, but you can use anything). After some research ended up using [bitcoin abe](https://github.com/jtobey/bitcoin-abe) and it worked great for me. Be patient though, it does take a long time - was several days in my case.